# Multiple imputation for missing values in R

Tags: r, spss

I would like to use imputation for replacing missing values in my data set. I have some constraints , for example I dont not want imputed variable `x1` be less than sum of my two other variables let say `x2 and x3`. I also want `x3` to be imputed by `0 or 14 or  >= 14 and` and x2 to be imputed by `0 or 16 or >= 16`. I tried to define these constraints in spss for example for multiple imputation, but in spss I can only define maximum and minimum. Is there any way to define furthur constraint in spss or do you know any R package which let me define these constraints for imputation of missing value?

```
   x1 =c(21, 50, 31, 15, 36, 82, 14, 14, 19, 18, 16, 36, 583, NA,NA,NA, 50, 52, 26, 24)
   x2 = c(0, NA, 18,0, 19, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,NA,NA, NA, 22, NA, 0, 0)
   x3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0)
   dat=data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3)
   > dat
       x1 x2 x3
   1   21  0  0
   2   50 NA  0
   3   31 18  0
   4   15  0  0
   5   36 19  0
   6   82  0 54
   7   14 NA  0
   8   14  0  0
   9   19  0  0
   10  18  0  0
   11  16  0  0
   12  36  0  0
   13 583  0  0
   14  NA NA NA
   15  NA NA NA
   16  NA NA NA
   17  50 22 NA
   18  52 NA  0
   19  26  0  0
   20  24  0  0
```

Comment: This is definitely possible, but demonstrating an answer will require some data, so please supply some sample data.

Comment: do you have only integers values?

Comment: @ Thomas. I have provided sample data.

Comment: Do you mean you just want values to fill those NA's satisfying the constraints but you don't what those values are exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only integers values, you can do something like this:

```
N <- 5
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x1 = sample(1:10,N,rep=TRUE),
                    x2 = sample(1:10,N,rep=TRUE),
                    x3 = sample(c(1,NA),N,rep=TRUE))

> dat
  x1 x2 x3
1  3  9  1
2  4 10  1
3  6  7 NA
4 10  7  1
5  3  1 NA
## x3 < sum(x1,x2)
transform(dat,x3 =ifelse(is.na(x3),sample(seq(x1+x2-1),1),x3))
  x1 x2 x3
1  3  9  1
2  4 10  1
3  6  7  3
4 10  7  1
5  3  1  3
## x3 in c(0,14)
transform(dat,x3 =ifelse(is.na(x3),sample(c(0,14),1),x3))
  x1 x2 x3
1  3  9  1
2  4 10  1
3  6  7 14
4 10  7  1
5  3  1 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could certainly do that in SPSS with simple transformation logic, but I would have thought that one would want to base the imputation on the distribution of the known values.